# Different ways to define arguments

Tags: python

what is the difference between these,

```
max(iterable, *[, key, default])
max(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])
iter(object[, sentinel])
input([prompt])
```

plus is there a documentation for more variations to these?
from what I understand,

`[, sentinel]` means `sentinel` is optional, maybe `prompt` is also optional

if i need to define multiple optional arguments then I use `*` like `*[, key, default]`

and for `*args[, key]`, there could be many optional `args` and one optional `key`.

but i would like to know all variations to these.

one more i saw,

```
itertools.accumulate(iterable[, func, *, initial=None])
```

maybe it means, `func` is optional argument, and `initial` is optional keyword argument

Answer (score 1):

```
max(iterable, *[, key, default])
```

The `key` and `default` are both optional, and must be specified [keyword-only](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/).

```
max(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])
```

Can be called with arbitrarily many arguments (at least 2) and `key` must be specified by keyword (since it comes after the *).

```
iter(object[, sentinal])
```

`sentinal` is optional.

```
input([prompt])
```

`prompt` is optional.